Get part of string with regex/ sql substr
I'm tying to extract a part of my string:



output
Fullstring
Expected Result




xi
xi-AN224432_-_this_is_some_text-x10.pdf
AN224432 or AN224432_


F1800X7T2P5P
xi-F1800X7T2P5P-blahblah-v01_00-EN.pdf
F1800X7T2P5P


1E303S
1E303S-blahblah-v01_20-EN.pdf
1E303S



The regex I tried is:
select 
    regexp(Fullstring ,'^(xi-)?(\[A-Za-z0-9\]+)-.\*','$2') output  

This returns the second row correctly, but not the first one.
The output I need is the alphanumeric number in between or it can be in start. "xi" needs to be omiited from the result, as it is not alpha numeric number, i need alpha numeric, if its "xi" in start i want to get the second part of the string, i didn't understand why for second row it showed correct but for first one it displayed 'xi'.
third is best case- as there is not xi in the start.

Explain why xi does not fit? Provide more in-depth description what can and can not be matched

What is your SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2)?  We need to know this in order to answer your question.

what dbms are you using?

You've tagged SQL Server. That has no function called regexp so I will remove that tag

"This returns the second row correctly, but not the first one." This simply isn't true, your query; on SQL Server, returns the error "'regexp' is not a recognized built-in function name." db<>fiddle Are you on a preview release of Azure SQL Database (which I believe does have some regex functions), or something?

@ThomA - Not one called regexp https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sql/introducing-regular-expression-regex-support-in-azure-sql-db/#feature-exploration

Yeah, I admit I didn't know what the new (proposed?) function names were, @MartinSmith .

I don't know which flavour of regex you are running, as usually we
would not escape the brackets. But this may be due to the syntax of
your regex engine. Up to you to see if you need them or not (also
for \* instead of *). The only doc I found is this page about
Denodo VQL regexp() function and it
mentions Java or Perl kind of syntax.
But what is missing is the optional underscore character "_" in your
pattern.
In Perl or PHP, it would be: ^(xi-)?(([A-Za-z0-9]+)_?)-.*
Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/DCxixu/1
I added a capturing group so that you can decide if you want to use the
full group with the underscore or if you want to drop it. You could even
replace _? by _* if they could be several of them.
